# Only certain operating systems will boot. No hardware issues found, but something must have broke

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, operating-systems

A custom machine from 2010, with the additional RAM and a new graphics card about 2 years. This machine quit booting Windows 7, some months ago. It stops at the windows logo on a black screen, but does not show the pulsing "window" graphic.

The machine **can** boot:

- Redo Backup (Ubuntu based, from multiboot USB)
- FreeDOS (from USB drive)

It **cannot** boot:

- Windows 7 (64 bit)
- Windows 7 USB installer (the same one used for the previous install)
- Windows 7 DVD
- Fedora Project 21, 23, or 24 (64 bit)
- Xubuntu 16.04 (64 bit)
- OpenSUSE 42.1 (64 bit, dd and iso)

Ran memory checks from BIOS and Linux. They found nothing.

Utilities run from Redo Backup pointed to a filesystem error (NTFS). Could not get chkdsk to run. So then the important files were backed up, and zeros were written to the drive. The boot-able list remained the same.

The extended SMART scan shows no problems with the drive (ran via the manufacturer's DOS utility).

Flashed the motherboard BIOS and reset its CMOS to defaults. What could be booted did not change.

Checked the power supply with a "tester": no faults. Physically reviewed the motherboard for defects: none found. Swapped the GPU with no difference made.

---

At this point, we are planning on swapping out the motherboard, though there only seems to be used ones available for an AM2+ with DDR2.

Comment: Looks some kind of hardware problem. Did you check the RAM? What happens if you try to boot a 32 bit Linux OS?

Comment: @dirkt, yes, I checked the memory twice: with the motherboard's baked-in utility, and from inside of Redo Backup. Downloading a 32 bit, Debian 8 now (though the system has more than 3GB of RAM).

Comment: If the system has a large amount of RAM, and works for 32 bit systems and FreeDOS, but not for 64bit, I'd still suspect bad RAM (bad 64bit mode on the CPU is somewhat unlikely). Sometimes bad RAM doesn't show up while testing, so try swapping/removing RAM sticks.

Comment: @dirkt, the 32bit booted showing 3GB of memory. For RAM, the system has 2x 2GB from the original build, but had 2x 1GB added a few years ago. I pulled the two newer sticks and booted a 64bit OS showing 4GB available. Since it had passed the memory tests, I never thought to bother pulling them. Hopefully, nothing is wrong with the CPU or the slots on the mobo, but I happen to have some other compatible chips around, so I will do some more testing.

Comment: @dirkt, If you write your comments up as an answer, then I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it worked before and suddenly stopped working, I suspect a hardware problem.

The fact that it can boot FreeDOS and (simpler) Linux systems, together with the comment that it has a lot of RAM, leads to the idea that possibly some of the RAM is bad, probably at higher addresses.

Sometimes bad RAM doesn't show up during RAM testing, so swapping or removing RAM sticks can help finding bad RAM, as long as not all RAM sticks are bad.

If it turns out the RAM was bad, it's rather unlikely other parts of the motherboard were damaged because of this.